# display:inline-block blocks word-wrap:break-word

Tags: html, css

I have got 2 divs aligned (treebold and totor), the second one may have long strings and i don't want ALL the text to go on a second line. I have searched on the internet for an answer without success. Do you have any solution ?

Explanation here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO5zK.jpg

```css
.treebold {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
}

.totor {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item_container">
  <div class="treebold" ng-bind="input1"></div>
  <div class="totor" ng-bind="input2_SOLONG"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little better how your end result should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for some layout code. Try adding `display: flex;` to your container, and then you can control how the two divs sit next to each other based on width or whatever you prefer.

```css
.item_container {
  display: flex;
}

.treebold {
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 150px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display:inline-block;
}

.totor {
  padding: 20px;
    word-wrap: break-word;    
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item_container">

  <div class="treebold" ng-bind="input1">Lorem ipsum dolor </div>

  <div class="totor" ng-bind="input2_SOLONG">Integer et nisl nunc. Praesent fermentum orci sed turpis consectetur, eu dapibus nisi tristique. </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust padding for ".treebold" as per your requirements.

```css
.item_container {
  display: flex;
}

.treebold {
  padding-right: 20px; 
}

.totor {
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item_container">

  <div class="treebold" ng-bind="input1">small content holder </div>

  <div class="totor" ng-bind="input2_SOLONG">This holder can have a very very very very long long long long content.Need to wrap it correctly using CSS </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing exactly what you want this to look like it is tough to say, but your solution could be as simple as `display: inline`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but  display:inline  doesn't help me ! 
I added an image for the explanation,